# As a consumer can I buy Ubuntu for my android phone somewhere?

Tags: tablet

Can Ubuntu for android plug into the monitor of a tablet as it's visual monitor so that the phone runs a computer on a tablet?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. PLease consider asking two separate questions rather than mashing them together. The answer to your title is no. But you can probably pay someone to install it for you. For the question in your text I can only surmise that you are misunderstanding something about the meaning of the words/phrases 'plug into', 'run a computer' or what ubuntu constitutes.

Comment: if you're serious i'll try this on my nexus 7.  what steps have you taken so far?  note that i don't have an hdmi out.  i only have a usb port...

Comment: Hi, yeah, I am not tech savvy but like the idea of ubunto on a phone acting like a computer when it is attached to a monitor (if I am understanding how that works).  I also would like to use a tablet as a monitor so that I could have what would be a laptop effectively - through my phone and a tablet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to buy Ubuntu for Android Phone ?!

How to get Ubuntu-Installer for Android is explained here :

http://www.redmondpie.com/install-and-run-ubuntu-on-your-android-device-with-ubuntu-installer-download-now/

For use of android/ubuntu - phone with e.g. notebook you need to install ubuntu-server.
But it would work too with ubuntu-desktop (installed and configurated on notebook).
A Tablet would be treated like a phone over W-LAN ?!

Comment: Click delete on the answer?

Comment: Do i need root to run this??

Comment: I think you are same like sudo - like when installing normal Ubuntu-Desktop.

Comment: Thanks dschinn1001.  So, as noted in my other comment, could I put Ubuntu-desktop onto a notebook so that I could use my phone and a notebook to function like a computer with a monitor?  Would act like a laptop when the phone was docked?